# using old .net library in .net core

Tags: .net, .net-core

I am working on a .net core project that needs a reference from existing .net 3rd party library which is built in .net4.5 framework. Would it be possible to reuse it on .net core projects?

Comment: You can wrap that library in a NuGet package, put in a custom feed, and then consume it in your .NET Core project. But since it only supports .NET Framework, your .NET Core project can only target desktop profiles/monikers.

Answer (score 2):

The majority of the libraries available in NuGet will not have support for Core. The only option is if the source code is available you will have to manually port it over.

Answer (score 0):

An old library would probably not work - the library would have to be built against a .NET Standard so that it supports both frameworks and runs across multiple platforms

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/standard/library

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cesardelatorre/2016/06/28/running-net-core-apps-on-multiple-frameworks-and-what-the-target-framework-monikers-tfms-are-about/

Comment: What if I don't care about multiple platflorms? Just Windows